# Assigning week number to a date

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have a list of dates in Columne A. I created a refernce table that has the Week Number, Week Start Date, and Week End Date. I want to have a formula that can go through my reference table and assign the week number if the date is within a Week Start and Week End Date.

**Example of Reference Table**
Week #        Week Start       Week End

1                   3/17/2014         3/23/24014 
2                   3/24/2014         3/30/2014 
3                   3/31/2014         3/30/3014

**Example of the Date List**
Date                      Week #
3/18/2014
3/19/2014
3/20/2014
3/21/2014
3/22/2014
...

Thank you

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but happy to learn a new function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a lookup table unless you have irregular "weeks"

```
=CEILING((A2-DATE(2014,3,16))/7,1)
```